# Elementary OS installation time resolution problem

Tags: resolution

I have downloaded the Freya version, burnt it into a DVD then i have booted with the DVD, after loading the welcome screen opens but the problem is the resolution is not correct, everything out there is so big that 80% of the contents doesn't fit into my screen. And that's the reason why i cant proceed further.

Comment: What monitor are you using? Is it a high-density one or a TV per chance?

Comment: Its normal one Asus VW161 1360 x 768 max resolution 16"